# Ubuntu Jammy Auto Install

Tags: 22.04, preseed, autoinstall

I am using an automated install for Ubuntu Jammy. I want to stop the prompt for installing updates and other software.

[image: image of message]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (based slightly on ["Updates and other software" in preseed ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441386/updates-and-other-software-in-preseed-ubuntu-22-04)):

Add these lines to the preseed file:

> ubiquity ubiquity/minimal_install boolean true
> ubiquity ubiquity/download_updates boolean false
> ubiquity ubiquity/install_oem boolean true

and this to the kernel options at boot:

> ubiquity/use_nonfree=true

This last one should also work as a preseed option ("ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree boolean true") but somehow it doesn't and has to be passed on via kernel opt. Using that I was able to finally automate a 22.04 desktop install via ubiquity.